# how to add and subtract a day either side of my datetime index in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with FOMC announcements dates in it and i want to have a new df with the FOMC date + the next day and also the previous day. As an example - 2017-06-13 has been added to the new df. Any ideas? i am using pandas 0.20.3 and Offsets looks like my best option.

```
2017-06-13
2017-06-14 The Federal Reserve, the central bank of the U... 
2017-06-15
2017-07-25
2017-07-26 The Federal Reserve, the central bank of the U... 
2017-07-27
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add or subtract `Timedelta`:

```
df['prev'] = df['date'] - pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d')
df['next'] = df['date'] + pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d')
print (df)
        date       prev       next
0 2017-06-13 2017-06-12 2017-06-14
1 2017-06-14 2017-06-13 2017-06-15
2 2017-06-15 2017-06-14 2017-06-16
3 2017-07-25 2017-07-24 2017-07-26
4 2017-07-26 2017-07-25 2017-07-27
5 2017-07-27 2017-07-26 2017-07-28
```

Or if need also `DataetimeIndex` is possible use [`Index.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.shift.html):

```
df = df.set_index('date')
df['prev'] = df.index.shift(-1, freq='d')
df['next'] = df.index.shift(1, freq='d')
print (df)
                 prev       next
date                            
2017-06-13 2017-06-12 2017-06-14
2017-06-14 2017-06-13 2017-06-15
2017-06-15 2017-06-14 2017-06-16
2017-07-25 2017-07-24 2017-07-26
2017-07-26 2017-07-25 2017-07-27
2017-07-27 2017-07-26 2017-07-28
```

And then use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
a = df['date'] - pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d')
b = df['date'] + pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d')

df = pd.concat([df['date'], a, b], ignore_index=True)
print (df)
0    2017-06-13
1    2017-06-14
2    2017-06-15
3    2017-07-25
4    2017-07-26
5    2017-07-27
6    2017-06-12
7    2017-06-13
8    2017-06-14
9    2017-07-24
10   2017-07-25
11   2017-07-26
12   2017-06-14
13   2017-06-15
14   2017-06-16
15   2017-07-26
16   2017-07-27
17   2017-07-28
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: both of the above solutions worked. Thankyou!!! is there a way to combine the dates in the same column using one line of code or do i need to merge columns?

Comment: Sorry, I am not understand. Do you need some new columns? Cna you explain more?

Comment: Or do you need instead `df['prev'] = df['date'] - pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d')
df['next'] = df['date'] + pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d')` one row solution?

Comment: Rather than have a column called 'prev' and 'next' , i would like the previous and after dates to be in the 'date' column. So the date column will show - 2017-06-13 2017-06-14 2017-06-15. If i create 'prev' and 'next' columns i have to merge the columns to achieve the one column with all dates in it.

Comment: So you need `df=pd.concat([df['date'], df['prev'], df['next']])` ?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what i wanted. Thank you Jezael.

Answer (score 3):

Using this sample dataset:

```
         date
0  2017-01-01
1  2017-01-02
2  2017-01-03
3  2017-01-04
4  2017-01-05
5  2017-01-06
6  2017-01-07
7  2017-01-08
```

We can use `pd.offsets.Day()` to add or subtract time values.

```
df['date_plus_one'] = df['date'] + pd.offsets.Day()
df['date_minus_one'] = df['date'] - pd.offsets.Day()

df
         date date_plus_one date_minus_one
0  2017-01-01    2017-01-02     2016-12-31
1  2017-01-02    2017-01-03     2017-01-01
2  2017-01-03    2017-01-04     2017-01-02
3  2017-01-04    2017-01-05     2017-01-03
4  2017-01-05    2017-01-06     2017-01-04
5  2017-01-06    2017-01-07     2017-01-05
6  2017-01-07    2017-01-08     2017-01-06
7  2017-01-08    2017-01-09     2017-01-07
```